# How to pass variable from php to jquery ajax as for its url parameter?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a newbie in the field of JavaScript so I have confusions. First of all I'm trying to load database table data when I click some text where I have mentioned `onclick` event inside the tag that closes some text.Each some text are also retrieved from database. So that means they have id allocated for them(some text).
The problem is how to pass the id of the particular row to the Jquery ajax show that it could be passed along with ajax url to another php file?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code. That way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: well sorry that my question was kinda confusing to all. Let me try again to explain my problem to u in details.   I have hotjobs.php file and hotjobsoutput.js file and api.php file. In hotjobs.php file my code is like:

Comment: <?php                                           

$sql=mysql_query("select * from hotjob"); 

$count=mysql_num_rows($sql); if($count>0){ while

($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){?><tr><td><?php echo 

$result['job_title'];?></td></tr><?php }}?>

                                                     

Now I want to get a row datas from database when I 

click its job_title name i.e $result['job_title'] using 

ajax jquery.

Comment: And my api.php file contains:    

                                                  <?php 
include("config.php");
$jobid=$_GET['jobid'];
$sql=mysql_query("select * from hotjobs where 

job_id='$jobid'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count==1){
$result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>

Comment: My hotjobsoutput.js file looks:                                                                    $function getrecord(id){
 var jobid=id;
 $.ajax({
     url:'hotjobdetails.php?',
     data:"jobid="+jobid,
     
     dataType:'json',
     success:function(data)
     {
      var jobtitle=data[1];

Comment: var refrence_no=data[2];
      var company=data[3];
      var country=data[4];
      var salary=data[5];
      var salaryincurrency=data[6];
      var dutyhours=data[7];
      var food=data[8];
      var accomodation=data[9];
      var medical=data[10];
      var overtime=data[11];
      var period=data[12];
      var leavedays=data[13];
      var joiningairticket=data[14];
      var returnairticket=data[15];
      var nofvaccancy=data[16];
      var note=data[17];

Comment: $("#hotjoboutput").html("<p>vaccancy for "+jobtitle+"</p><table border=1px cellpadding=2px>
         <tr><td>Refrence_no</td><td>"+Refrence_no+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Company</td><td>"+company+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Country</td><td>"+country+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Salary</td><td>"+salary+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Salary in Currency</td><td>"+salaryincurrency+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Duty </td><td>"+dutyhours+"</td></tr>
         <tr colspan=2>Terms and conditions</tr>
         <tr><td>Food</td><td>"+food+"</td></tr>

Comment: <tr><td>Accomodation</td><td>"+accomodation+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Medical</td><td>"+medical+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Overtime</td><td>"+overtime+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Period of contract</td><td>"+period+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Leave</td><td>"+leavedays+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Joining Air Ticket</td><td>"+joiningairticket+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Return Air Ticket</td><td>"+returnairticket+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>No of Vaccancy</td><td>"+nofvaccancy+"</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Note</td><td>"+note+"</td></tr>
         </table>");
     }
     });
});

Comment: To do so I need to pass $result['job_title']'s 
particular id to ajax jquery source code (hotjoboutput.js)  so that the id could be passed to 

api.php file as ajax url parameter.
                                                                 That's it ! all i need is the code to 
work. But its not working.M i clear now? plz do suggest. Sry that i couldnt write my whole comment in a single box, i dont know how to do that. Its beacause of limit of characters per comment. hope u will cooperate with me. Well if its not clear again i want to ask it more clearly. plz help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, before you ask for an answer, please show us some examples of your work. What have you done to try to tackle this problem.

You can simply output any php data in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = "<?php echo $my_var; ?>";
</script>
```

Based on that you can try yourself to output your id to the end of URL in your AJAX call.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work if you have a policy of forbidding inline javascript in favor of .js-Files

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to pass data to javscript is by creating a hidden form with hidden inputs:

```
<form id="jsData">
    <?php foreach($data as $key=>$value): ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="<?= htmlspecialchars($key, ENT_QUOTES) ?>" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>">
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

You get the data with $('#keyxxx').val();

You can also use other hidden HTML elements to pass data to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs on the client and php on the server. 
You can't direct use a js variable on php. BUT you have some resources to do that.
Try to use the POST method that can transfer information from server to client.
an example of that in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Now i don't know the flow of the data in your code.
What i used was:

```
<?php 
 $phpvar="yourvalue";
 echo '<script>var i="'.$phpvar.'";</script>';
?>
```

See if it helps in your case.